# Recoding all but one variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode all but one type of element in a column **inside a function**. The column name changes depending on the input of the function, and also the element in the column which shouldn't be recoded changes depending on the function input.

the data frame (df in code snippet) looks as follows:

| ... | education | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | bachelor | ... |
| ... | master | ... |
| ... | high school | ... |
| ... | high school | ... |
| ... | master | ... |

but could also look like

| ... | gender | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | male | ... |
| ... | female | ... |
| ... | female | ... |
| ... | female | ... |
| ... | male | ... |

The output that I want is the following respectively:

| ... | education | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | bachelor | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |

| ... | gender | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | male | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | rest | ... |
| ... | male | ... |

I have tried the following:

```
select_data <- function(df, col_name, do_not_change){
     df <- df %>%
       dplyr::mutate('{col_name}' = recode(col_name, '{do_not_change}' := {{do_not_change}}, .default = "rest"))
```

So the calls would look as follows respectively:

```
# case of education
education_df <- function(df, education, 'bachelor')
# case of gender
gender_df <- function(df, gender, 'male')
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be modified to

```
select_data <- function(df, col_name, do_not_change){
     df %>%
       dplyr::mutate({{col_name}} := recode({{col_name}}, 
           {{do_not_change}} := {{do_not_change}}, .default = "rest"))
      
       }
```

and call as

```
select_data(df, gender, 'male')  
  gender   education
1   male    bachelor
2   rest      master
3   rest high school
4   male      master
```

---

If we need to pass a string, use `ensym` which can work with both quoted/unquoted input

```
select_data <- function(df, col_name, do_not_change){
   col_name <- rlang::ensym(col_name)
     df %>%
       dplyr::mutate({{col_name}} := recode(!! col_name, 
           {{do_not_change}} := {{do_not_change}}, .default = "rest"))
      
       }
```

-testing

```
> select_data(df, 'gender', 'male') 
  gender   education
1   male    bachelor
2   rest      master
3   rest high school
4   male      master
> select_data(df, gender, 'male')
  gender   education
1   male    bachelor
2   rest      master
3   rest high school
4   male      master
```

---

If we pass both arguments as quoted or unquoted

```
select_data <- function(df, col_name, do_not_change){
   col_name <- rlang::ensym(col_name)
   do_not_change <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(do_not_change))
     df %>%
       dplyr::mutate({{col_name}} := recode(!! col_name, 
           {{do_not_change}} := {{do_not_change}}, .default = "rest"))
      
       }
```

-testing

```
> select_data(df, 'gender', 'male') 
  gender   education
1   male    bachelor
2   rest      master
3   rest high school
4   male      master
> select_data(df, gender, male)
  gender   education
1   male    bachelor
2   rest      master
3   rest high school
4   male      master
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male"), 
    education = c("bachelor", "master", "high school", "master"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey @akrun, I don't know where the rest of the previous thread went, but wanted to say thank you for the help. All works well now for me!

Comment: @TomMcDonald probably the mods have deleted the comments

Answer (score 1):

Would this work ?

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    gender = ifelse(gender == "male", "male", "rest"),
    education = ifelse(education == "bachelor", "bachelor", "rest"))
```

Comment: I guess this works, but I need it such that it's just for 1. So either gender or education. And what I also need is that it changes based on the col_name and the do_not_change parameter